# The definitions of finitely presented modules?

Tags: modules, representation-theory

Let $M$ be a module over a ring or an algebra $A$.I have seen three definitions of finitely presented modules:

(1) A module $M$ is called finitely presented if there is an exact sequence of $A$-modules: $0 \rightarrow L \rightarrow F \rightarrow M \rightarrow 0$, where $F$ is a free module of finite rank, $L$ is finitely generated;

(2) A module $M$ is called finitely presented if there is an exact sequence of $A$-modules: $F_2 \rightarrow F_1 \rightarrow M \rightarrow 0$, with $F_1,F_2$ free modules of finite rank;

(3) A module $M$ is called finitely presented if there is an exact sequence of $A$-modules: $P_2 \rightarrow P_1 \rightarrow M \rightarrow 0$, with $P_1,P_2$ finitely generated projetive modules.

I can get (2) by (1), get (3) by (2). But I can't get they are equivalent. So who can tell me how to prove they are equivalent?

Comment: In the first definition, isn't there a term missing in the exact sequence? The last morphism should be surjective.

Comment: Yes, I have edited it. Thank you for your advice.

Comment: To Go from 3 to 1 just replace $P_2$ by its image under the map to $P_1$.

Comment: @Mariano Suárez-Álvarez♦ But condition (1) needs the middle term to be a free module of finite rank, and L to be finitely generated. I know a projective module can be completed to a free module, but I can't make sure the free module is of finite rank and L to be finitely generated.

Comment: Just add to the middle term whatever you need to make it free (and a copy of that on the third term)

Comment: Well, show that a finitely generated projective is a direct summand of a finitely generated free module!

Comment: Yes, a finitely generated projetive module can be added to be a finitely generated free module. But do you mean also add that to M to make the sequence exact?  It would not be the form $0 \rightarrow L \rightarrow F \rightarrow M \rightarrow 0$, i.e. the fourth term isn't M again

Comment: Also if you replace $P_2$ by its image in $P_1$, we denote by $L$, how to make sure $L$ is finitely generated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $$P_2\to P_1\to A\to 0$$ is as in (3).  Since $P_1$ is finitely generated and projective, there is a finitely generated module $Q$ such that $P_1\oplus Q=F$ is a finite rank free module.  Now take the direct sum of our exact sequence and the exact sequence $$Q\stackrel{1_Q}\to Q\to 0\to 0$$ to get another exact sequence $$P_2\oplus Q\stackrel{f}\to F\stackrel{g}\to A\to 0.$$  Since $P_2$ and $Q$ are finitely generated, $\operatorname{im}(f)=\ker(g)$ is finitely generated (it is generated by the images of generators of $P_2$ and $Q$ under $f$).  Let $L=\ker(g)$.  We then have a short exact sequence $$0\to L\to F\stackrel{g}\to A\to 0$$ which satisfies the requirements of (1).